# Syntactic link between ZFC and first order logic

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, foundations

Suppose that I connect syntactically the first order logic with ZFC by changing $\forall x \phi(x)$ by if $x$ is a set then $\phi (x)$ stating that x is not free in "if $x$ is a set then $\phi (x)$" in the same sense of "$\forall x \phi(x)$", use this change to eliminate the existential quantifier and call the new language ZFC'. I understand that ZFC' is not longer under first order logic so it may not make sense to talk about semantic using model theory. My question is: intuitively everything that can be proved in ZFC (without using semantic) can be proved in ZFC' and vice versa? For me, the answer is yes but I am not sure.

The idea is not substitute a symbol ($\forall$) for other with same meaning because the yes answer would be trivial. The intended meaning for "if $x$ is a set then $\phi (x)$" is "if $x\in U$ then $\phi (x)$" where $U$ is the universe that does not exist in ZFC.

Comment: See [set theory with *atoms* (or *urelements*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement): is a version of $\mathsf {ZF}$ where the "universe" is not restricted to sets and we have a predicate $S(x)$ that specify what objects of the domain are *sets* (or, equivalently, a predicate $U(x)$ specifying what objects are not sets).

Comment: Interesting, it is a related idea, but I am looking how to use S(x) to use instead quantification. Thanks.